# Cruise to US Islands after a Cuba visit

Tags: esta, cruising, cuba, us-virgin-islands

We visited Cuba this year with TUI and have booked a Caribbean cruise next March with TUI. The cruise stops at US Virgin Island & Puerto Rico. TUI explained that we would need ESTAs for US Islands. Ok fine.

But I found out today that because we have been to Cuba we have to get a full US visa not ESTAs. I went into TUI shop, but they have no knowledge about Cuba & full visas for our cruise.

Can we get on the plane and can we board the ship without the visas? We were just going to stay on the ship for those two ports and not set foot on the Islands.

Comment: What country's passport do you carry? What is the actual itinerary (departure port, all stop-overs, arrival port) of the cruise...or even better, what is the TUI name of the specific cruise for which you hold tickets?

Comment: Apply for the visa now, you still have a chance to get it in time before next March

Comment: "I found out today that because we have been to Cuba we have to get a full US visa not ESTAs": why?  Where did you see this? Cuba is not on [the list of countries where past presence disqualifies you from participating in the visa waiver program](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html).  See also https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/visa-waiver-program/visa-waiver-program-improvement-and-terrorist-travel-prevention-act-faq

Comment: Here is an official source that mentions this: https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/faq (search for "Cuba").

Answer (score 2):

That's a question the cruise provider should answer, it depends on whether they expect the ships to be empty while in port or not.

*Usually* for most cruises you're allowed to stay on the ship if you don't want to disembark.

As to visas, it's your responsibility to confirm you have all the necessary visas for your travel.

Comment: "Usually for most cruises you're allowed to stay on the ship" - I believe the US requires everyone on the ship to clear immigration even if they wish to remain on board.

Comment: @Midavalo any source for that? I'm not familiar with such a regulation. I also don't believe there's a US pre-clearance facility in Cuba.

Comment: only personal experience.  EVERY cruise I've done that's stopped in the US (including those that have started in the US and then returned there) have required all passengers and crew to clear immigration.  In fact they required all off the ship and would not allow any to re-board until the last one had cleared.  This was always done at the US port, not pre-cleared.  Which, to me, would suggest that all passengers would require correct travel docs for the US before the cruise started.

Comment: @Midavalo which to me suggest that the passenger should clear the requirements with the cruise line. That said, I couldn't find any mention of such a requirement on any of the US government pages

Comment: I agree - the cruise line should know and provide info on the requirements and whether this would be allowed.

Comment: The cruise line may well say what the requirements are — [this prior question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174295/will-i-need-canada-visitor-visa-while-traveling-on-alaska-cruise/174296#174296) illustrates the point — but the cruise line's T&C will undoubtedly confirm the passenger's ultimate responsibility. "They gave me the wrong advice" will not be a  productive response.