# How would America know if I have docked in Cuba but not got off the ship?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, cruising

How would america know if I have docked in Cuba but not got off the ship regarding applying for an ESTA and not a visa?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/176775/will-us-immigration-know-about-prior-travel-to-cuba-if-a-vwp-national-has-no-cub/176829#176829 Consider that even if they do not know, if they notice anything that makes them think that you may have been to Cuba and not told them, it will be up to you to prove you didn't get off the ship. Proving a negative is usually not very easy.

Comment: It likely wouldn't matter if you go off the ship or not, you were in port.  I can't say for sure if CBP shares data with CARICOM but I'd lean toward yes.  That's how CBP would know you were in Cuba.